# Add element to Firestore array

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I have an empty array in Firestore dashboard. And I'm trying to add some item to it. I've followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), but no result. I don't want to sore and rewrite this element.

My gradle contains:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
```

and my code:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue
```

...

```
val documentReference = firestore.collection("events")
                .document(event.firebaseUserUid + "-" + event.title)
    documentReference
                .update("participants", (FieldValue.arrayUnion(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)) )
```

But FieldValue.arrayUnion doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newest version of firestore now supports it:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think support for that has actually been added to the Android API, despite its documentation as such on the page you linked.

It's missing from the [Android API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue), but is present in the [Web API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.arrayUnion) as well as the [Web changelog](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js).